Positivity Assumption in Propensity Score Methods for Pre- and Post-Treatment
I am designing a research project and could use some guidance. My research question focuses on estimating the effect of a new co-responder policing program on use-of-force and arrests. I want to see if the implementation of the co-responder program resulted in a decrease in use-of-force and arrests during interventions. The cases are police interventions following a 911 call for service. The treatment variable is a binary if a co-responder team responded to the incident (1) or if the police as-usual responded (0). To avoid contamination, I want to have all control cases come from a time before the program began since all officers in this police department have received program training. Treatment cases will be drawn from incidents after the implementation of the program. To avoid selection bias, I want to use propensity score methods to match treatment cases with control cases. However, based on what I'm reading, the positivity assumption of propensity score methods may be violated because there was zero probability that cases in the control group could have been allocated to the treatment (Harris & Horst, 2016). It seems as though I may be able to address this through a difference-in-differences approach. However, I do not see how I can identify a treatment group in the time period before the treatment was implemented because all calls were eligible to receive co-response.
I would like some guidance on the positivity assumption and how to modify my analysis structure. I've seen a paper do pre-post analysis with propensity scores without addressing positivity (Blais & Brisebois, 2021). I know this doesn't imply statistical rigor, but it makes me question if this a necessary assumption to address in my analytical design? If so, how can I get around it to ensure my analysis is statistically robust - is difference-in-differences applicable here, or is there a better technique? Any direction would be appreciated.
